# How to group and Sum of hrs based on the key value in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

Can you please suggest xslt code on how to get the results based on the below
xml on group by Week value. The expected output should be:

```
Year Week Tot Hrs  Ben Hrs
2015 33    80.7       0
2015 34    120.7      0
```

Advance thanks for your help

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   -<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/TLB024_TEST">
 -<wd:Report_Entry>
  -<wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
   <wd:FISCAL_YEAR>2015</wd:FISCAL_YEAR>
    <wd:FISCAL_WEEK>33</wd:FISCAL_WEEK>
    <wd:TOT_HRS>40</wd:TOT_HRS>
    <wd:BEN_HRS>0</wd:BEN_HRS>
    </wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
 -<wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
   <wd:FISCAL_YEAR>2015</wd:FISCAL_YEAR>
    <wd:FISCAL_WEEK>33</wd:FISCAL_WEEK>
    <wd:TOT_HRS>0.07</wd:TOT_HRS>
    <wd:BEN_HRS>0</wd:BEN_HRS>
    </wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
  -<wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
   <wd:FISCAL_YEAR>2015</wd:FISCAL_YEAR>
    <wd:FISCAL_WEEK>34</wd:FISCAL_WEEK>
    <wd:TOT_HRS>40</wd:TOT_HRS>
    <wd:BEN_HRS>0</wd:BEN_HRS>
    </wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
   -<wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
    <wd:FISCAL_YEAR>2015</wd:FISCAL_YEAR>
    <wd:FISCAL_WEEK>34</wd:FISCAL_WEEK>
    <wd:TOT_HRS>0.07</wd:TOT_HRS>
    <wd:BEN_HRS>0</wd:BEN_HRS>
    </wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
 -<wd:Report_Entry>
   -<wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
    <wd:FISCAL_YEAR>2015</wd:FISCAL_YEAR>
    <wd:FISCAL_WEEK>33</wd:FISCAL_WEEK>
    <wd:TOT_HRS>40</wd:TOT_HRS>
    <wd:BEN_HRS>0</wd:BEN_HRS>
    </wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
  -<wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
    <wd:FISCAL_YEAR>2015</wd:FISCAL_YEAR>
    <wd:FISCAL_WEEK>34</wd:FISCAL_WEEK>
    <wd:TOT_HRS>40</wd:TOT_HRS>
    <wd:BEN_HRS>0</wd:BEN_HRS>
    </wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
  -<wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

XSLT :

This is the xslt code, I tried not able to get the desire result.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/TLB024_TEST" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:template match="/|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">

    <File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt">
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE">
            <Record>
                <xsl:variable name="Group" select="../wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE[((wd:FISCAL_YEAR=current()/wd:FISCAL_YEAR) and (wd:FISCAL_WEEK=current()/wd:FISCAL_WEEK)]" />
                <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id($Group[1])">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <fiscal_year xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="wd:FISCAL_YEAR"/></fiscal_year>
                    <fiscal_week xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="wd:FISCAL_WEEK"/></fiscal_week>
                    <tot_hrs xtt:fixedLength="7" xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($Group/wd:TOT_HRS), '0.##')"/></tot_hrs>
                    <ben_hrs xtt:fixedLength="7" xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($Group/wd:BEN_HRS), '0.##')"/></ben_hrs>
                    <Filler><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></Filler>
                </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
             </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </File>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you should indicate what did you try before asking answers...

Comment: I tried with this code.. not able to get desired result

Comment: You forgot to show us the wanted result ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, this is a very simple grouping problem:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="wd:PAYROLL_RESULT_LINE"
  group-by="concat(wd:FISCAL_YEAR, '/', wd:FISCAL_WEEK)">
            <Record>
                    <fiscal_year xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="wd:FISCAL_YEAR"/></fiscal_year>
                    <fiscal_week xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="wd:FISCAL_WEEK"/></fiscal_week>
                    <tot_hrs xtt:fixedLength="7" xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/wd:TOT_HRS), '0.##')"/></tot_hrs>
                    <ben_hrs xtt:fixedLength="7" xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/wd:BEN_HRS), '0.##')"/></ben_hrs>
                    <Filler><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></Filler>
             </Record>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Michael, could you please explain why current-group() is required here, and wd:TOT_HRS is not sufficient? From my very limited understanding of XSLT, I thought that within for-each-group instruction the nodes are grouped already, so sum(wd:TOT_HRS) would seem sufficient, but of course it doesn't work without current-group(). Thanks.

Comment: `sum(X)` sums over the X children of the context item, while `sum(current-group()/X)` sums over the X children of all the nodes in the current group. Within `xsl:for-each-group`, the context item is the first item in the current group.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thank you, Michael.